# Nokia C100/1616 SPI TFT with ESP8266

Tags: spi, esp8266, glcd

I am making a wifi scanner with ESP8266 and to display information I am using SPI based Nokia 1616/C100 display.

This time I am coding ESP8266 natively rather than using mcu + esp8266 (running at command firmware) combination.

On the ESP side I have successfully coded the hardware spi (HSPI) to spit out 9 bit values in the proper format (msb first, spi mode 0). I can see the data being sent on spi just fine.

[image]

However when I connect the LCD, there is nothing on it. Its just plain  white with backlight as if it's not even getting initialized. The initializatin code that I have used works just fine (with an AVR for a different project)

```
void LCD_NOKIA_C100_init(void)
{
//SET GPIO4 AS OUTPUT FOR RST LINE
PIN_FUNC_SELECT(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_GPIO4_U, FUNC_GPIO4);
GPIO_OUTPUT_SET(4, 1);

LCD_NOKIA_C100_RST_LOW;
//DELAY FOR 200us
os_delay_us(200);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_RST_HIGH;
//DELAY FOR 10MS
os_delay_us(10000);

//SOFTWARE RESET
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x01);
os_delay_us(5000);

//SLEEP OUT + BOOSTER ON
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x11);
os_delay_us(6000);

//PARTIAL DISPLAY OFF
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x13);

os_delay_us(6000);

//INTERFACE PIXEL FORMAT = RGB (5 6 5)
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x3A);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x05);

//DISPLAY ON
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x29);

//SET GAMMA PROFILE
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x26);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x08);
}

void LCD_NOKIA_C100_clear_screen(uint16_t color)
{
uint8_t h = (color>>8);
uint8_t l = (color);

//CASET (COLS = 0 TO 131)
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x2A);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x00);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x00);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x00);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(131);

//RASET (ROWS = 0 TO 161)
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x2B);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x00);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x00);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(0x00);
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(161);

//RAMWR
LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_command(0x2C);

uint16_t i;
for(i=0; i<(132*162); i++)
{
    LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(h);
    LCD_NOKIA_C100_send_data(l);
}
}
```

I have a feeling that this is something ESP specific but I don't have enough experience with it to pinpoint it.

The TFT is connected to ESP8266 as follows

### ESP8266  ---  NOKIA TFT

/RST ----------- GPIO4
/CS  ----------- GPIO15 (HSPI)
SDA  ----------- GPIO13 (HSPI)
SCK  ----------- GPIO14 (HSPI)

Comment: SDA and SCK on the Nokia display side looks like I2C, not SPI...

Comment: The interface is confirmed spi as I have used is successfully with an AVR

Comment: Do you have any solutions for this user's new [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/401838/connecting-the-display-from-nokia-c100-1616-spi-tft-to-esp-12)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a debugging question which the asker abandoned many years ago

Comment: Maybe the display is 5 V logic thus it works with 5 V arduino, but ESP has 3.3 V interface?!

Answer (score 1):

The ESP8266 clock speed is high enough that you can use bitbanging technique to drive the GPIO for 9 bit SPI. If there is a command called DAL (Display All pixels ON) ,then it makes the entire screen white without affecting the Display RAM. It seems the initialization code is just fine. I find a problem with the CASET and RASET part. After sending command for CASET, you have to send two data signals (ie, y axis start and y axis end ye and ys which lies between 0 to 131). I find 4 data signals followed by RASET and CASET command. I also suspect that SLEEP OUT have different command and BOOSTER ON have separate command.

---

I'll first recommend you to use bitbanding technique, then check once of its working. If it works, then you move to SPI technique.